# Legend position in standalone pgfplot moves when plot is used in document

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, positioning, standalone, legend

The following mwe shows that the legend position in a pgfplot changes when the standalone version is scaled in a document that includes it.

Standalone:

[image]

From driver:

[image]

(I changed the sizes to post smaller pictures.)

Here's the mwe:

Standalone:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=comma]{
category, mass, other
{dollars\\\$3.14m}, 31, 69
{donors\\56k}, 21, 79
}\warren

\newcommand{\plotsize}{width=6cm, height=5cm} 
\newcommand{\legendoffset}{(0.185, 0.5)} %fraction of plotsize

\pgfplotsset{every axis legend/.append 
  style={at={\legendoffset},anchor=north west}
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ 
    ybar stacked,
    ymin=0,
    ymax=100,
    bar width=35pt,
    enlarge x limits={abs=20pt},
    \plotsize,
    hide y axis,
    axis x line*=top,
    axis line style={opacity=0},
    xtick style={opacity=0},
    xtick=data,
    xticklabel style={align=center},
    xticklabel pos=upper,
    xticklabels from table={\warren}{category},
    point meta=explicit,
    ]
  \legend{Massachusetts, out of state};
  \addplot [fill=blue] table [x expr =\coordindex, y=mass, meta=mass] {\warren};
  \addplot [fill=yellow] table [x expr =\coordindex, y=other,
    meta=other]{\warren};    
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The driver:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\newcommand{\scalepicture}{15cm}

\begin{document}
\resizebox{\scalepicture}{!}
{
\input{mwe}
}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** The following guess was wrong - I'm glad no one invested time to implement it.

I'm pretty sure this happens because the legend position is specified relative to the plot size while the other plot features like `nodes near coords` have absolute positions that scale properly. If I'm right then one possible solution is

```
\newcommand{\calculatelegendoffset}[5]{%
 % #1 plotwidth (cm)
 % #2 plotheight (cm)
 % #3 legendxposition (cm)
 % #4 legendyposition (cm)
 % #5 scalefactor
}
```

But of course any elegant general solution is welcome.

Comment: @Jake It took me much longer to ask the question than for you to answer it! Please post your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`resizebox` only stretches or shrinks its entire content, it cannot rearrange the components within a drawing. The problem here comes from the fact that you're using different font sizes in the standalone and the main document. If you put `12pt` in the options of the standalone document as well, the legend position is identical.